# Sqlite Parameterized insert query (escape)

Tags: sql, .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Hi I try to use SQLite Parameterized query
but in the column name is a DOT (.)

```
INSERT INTO Data (`test.1`, `test.2`, `test.3`) VALUES (@test.1, @test.3,@test.3)
```

Returns

> "SQL logic error or missing database near ".": syntax error"

```
INSERT INTO Data (`test.1`, `test.2`, `test.3`) VALUES ([@test.1], [@test.3],[@test.3])
```

Returns

> "SQL logic error or missing database
>   no such column: @test.1"

how can i escape the dot and still use the names as parameters!?

Comment: did you try the same [ & ] for column names too?

Comment: no i did not,  let me check!!!

did not work.. same error as second example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "proper" escape character in SQLite is double quotes:

```
INSERT INTO Data("test.1", "test.2", "Test.3")
    VALUES ([@test1], [@test3], [@test3])
```

Leave the `.` out of the parameter name -- presumably, you have control over that.

SQLite explicitly supports the backtick for compatibility with MySQL and the square braces for compatibility with MS Access and SQL Server.  (As you can see in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).)

Comment: oke whas hoping for a escaping solution. but i think this would be the best solution. now i do not need the brackets [ & ] anymore